# Get Random Location From Coordinates

Tags: java, random

How can I get a random number within bounds? I have an X, Y, and Z coordinate for the min and max bounds (this is a videogame). How can I get a random coordinate that lies within those boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an integer, use the Random class:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

To generate the integer:

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;  // This will return a random int between min and max
```

To generate a random float (Random class not needed)

```
Min + (Math.random() * (Max - Min))
```

Comment: `Min + (Math.random() * (Max - Min))` worked for me! Just waiting to accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
(Math.random() * upperLimit) + lowerLimit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] getRandomVect
(float minX, float minY, float minZ, float maxX, float maxY, float maxZ)
{
      //Vectors can be translated, multipled or scaled later
      float[] result=new float[3];
      result[0]=Math.random()*(maxX-minX)+minX;
      result[1]=Math.random()*(maxY-minY)+minY;
      result[2]=Math.random()*(maxZ-minZ)+minZ;
      return result;
}

 //later usage:
 float [] randomVector= getRandomVect(2,2,3,5,5,10); 
 // makes vector's X  between 2 and 5
 // Y between 2 and 5
 // Z between 3 and 10
```